# $1$ is not congruent because of Fermat's Last Theorem?

Tags: intuition, irrational-numbers, proof-explanation

I would like someone to explain something I did not understand. I was reading a page called "nuking the mosquito" where they give very complex proofs for very simple results.

The proof I want to talk about deals with the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.

If $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, then there is a right angeled equilateral triangle with sides $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2},2)$. The area of this triangle is $1$, and if we assume $\sqrt{2}$ is rational then $1$ is congruent.

Then the writer says "Hence $1$ is congruent. This contradicts Fermat's Last Theorem with exponent $4$"

I don't doubt that $1$ is not congruent, I just don't see the connection to FLT. Would anyone shed some light to what I'm missing?

Comment: That would be an isosceles triangle not equilateral as equilateral would make all sides be the same. $a^4+b^4=c^4$ would have a non-trivial solution since the $\sqrt2$ could be expressed as a fraction that would give a solution which was part of FLT.

Comment: Well with a right angled equilateral triangle, you might as well prove the Riemann hypothesis as well.

Comment: I meant isosceles. I should have paid more attention during English classes...I still don't fully understand. Why is $\sqrt{2}$ being rational imply that there is a non trivial (non zero?) solution to $a^4+b^4=c^4$?

Comment: Look here, the first answer...http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts

Comment: From the same thread, next page http://mathoverflow.net/posts/125812/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, then there exists an isosceles triangle has side lengths $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2},2)$. This triangle has area $1$; hence $1$ would be a congruent number. This contradicts Fermat with $n=4$; see Theorem $2.1$ in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2007/congnumber.pdf for the relation to Fermat.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You need to say more to make explicit the linke with FLT$_4$, since that is not done in your link.

Comment: @Bill Sorry, wrong link. See Thm 2.1 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2007/congnumber.pdf.

Answer (score -1):

Pierre de Fermat wrote in the 17th century that:
" I have discovered a truly marvelous demonstration of this proposition that this margin is too narrow to contain."

Hypothesize
z^3=x^3+y^3.

2^3+4^3=8+64=72.
10^2-1^2-3^3=72.

So
2^3+4^3=10^2-1^2-3^3=[4(4+1)/2]^2  -  [2(2-1)/2]^2 - [ (2+1)^3 ].

2^3+8^3=8+512=520.
36^2-1^2-(3^3+4^3+5^3+6^3+7^3)=36^2-1^2-(27+64+125+216+343)=1296-776=520.

So
2^3+8^3=36^2-1^2-(3^3+4^3+5^3+6^3+7^3)=[8(8+1)/2]^2 - [2(2-1)/2]^2 - [(2+1)^3+(2+2)^3+........+(8-2)^3+(8-1)^3]

Rules of the integer
x^3+y^3=[y(y+1)/2]^2 – [x(x-1)/2]^2 – [ (x+1)^3+(x+2)^3+........+a^3+..........+(y-2)^3+(y-1)^3 ]

So
a^3=[y(y+1)/2]^2 – [x(x-1)/2]^2 – [ (x+1)^3+(x+2)^3+...+(a-1)^3+(a+1)^3+............+(y-2)^3+(y-1)^3 ] - z^3.

Required to have the triad (z,x,y integer) for every (a).
However, there exists at least one of (a) such that z, x, y are not the integers.

So
z^n =/ x^n+y^n  .

Ishtar.