# Unsolvability of a diophantine equation is equivalent to a given mathematical case

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-equations

Our math teacher tells us that he read that showing Riemann hypothesis is true was equivalent to showing a particular diophantine equation doesn't have any solution. He asked us to make a list of cases in mathematics of the form:

Case A is true if and only if a particular diophantine equation doesn't have any solution.

My google searching return only the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: You may also want to ask this on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, $n=1$ is not a [congruent number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number) if and only if $X^4+Y^4=Z^4$ has no nontrivial integer solution.

Reference: [$1$ is not congruent because of Fermat's Last Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902469/1-is-not-congruent-because-of-fermats-last-theorem)

Another example is, that every elliptic curve of $\Bbb Q$ is modular if and only if $X^n+Y^n=Z^n$ has no nontrivuial integer solution for all $n\ge 3$ (Modularity conjecture, Taniyama-Shimura Conjecture and FLT).

Comment: Very interesting. I am seeking open problems with this property: Unsolvability of a diophantine equation is equivalent to a given mathematical open problem.